# ORA-04091 table is Mutating

Tags: oracle, triggers, mutating-table, ora-04091

i have the following 2 table:
runs:

```
+--------+-------------+
| run_id | status      |
+========+=============+
| 1      | active      |
+--------+-------------+
| 2      | new         |
+--------+-------------+
```

and orders:

```
+----------+--------+--------------+
| order_id | run_id | order_status |
+==========+========+==============+
| 1        | 1      | finished     |
+----------+--------+--------------+
| 2        | 1      | finished     |
+----------+--------+--------------+
| 3        | 1      | active       |
+----------+--------+--------------+
| 4        | 2      | new          |
+----------+--------+--------------+
| 5        | 2      | active       |
+----------+--------+--------------+
| 6        | 2      | active       |
+----------+--------+--------------+
```

it is requested to implement the following logic: **when all orders in the run have the same status the run status should be updated (to be the same as its orders)**.

for example when the the `order_id = 3` status is set to `'finished'` then the `run_id=1` status should be set to `'finished'` too. the same with `order_id = 4` when it takes the status `'active'` then `run_id = 2 should` set to `'active'` too.

the procedure responsible of checking orders status and updating run status accordingly:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE  check_and_update_run_status  (in_order_id     IN   orders.order_id%TYPE,
                                                           in_run_id       IN   runs.run_id%TYPE,
                                                           in_order_status IN   orders.order_status%TYPE)
AS
   v_update_run VARCHAR2(1) := 'N';
BEGIN
   /*query the table ORDERS and check if all orders in the given in_run_id having the same status as in_order_status: */
  SELECT CASE
           WHEN NOT EXISTS ( SELECT *
                                 FROM ( SELECT order_id,
                                               order_status
                                          FROM orders
                                         WHERE run_id = in_run_id )
                                WHERE order_status <> in_order_status )
             THEN 'Y'
           END
    INTO v_update_run
    FROM dual;

    IF v_update_run THEN
      UPDATE runs
         SET run_status = in_order_status
       WHERE run_id = in_run_id;
    END IF;

END check_and_update_run_status;
```

and I've created the trigger

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trigger1 
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OF order_status ON orders FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
  check_and_update_run_status( in_order_id  => :new.order_id,
                               in_run_id    => :new.run_id,
                               in_po_status => :new.order_status );
END;
```

the logic is failing because the error: **`ORA-04091: table ORDERS is mutating, trigger/function may not see it`**.
the trigger is calling a procedure which querying the same table the trigger is invoked against.

what would the best way to solve such a problem?

Comment: What happens in case e.g. for `run_id = 3` there are  `order_id = 7` has `order_status = 'new'` and `order_id = 8` has `order_status = 'new'` and then there is an update to status happened for `order_id = 7` from `new` to `active`, what will be the status in `runs` table ? will it stay as `new` or should change to `active` ?

Comment: @Sujitmohanty30: it will stay as new. run_status will be switched when all orders in the run have the same status.

Comment: Ok Thanks for the clarification. Which version of oracle are you using ?

Comment: @Sujitmohanty30 12c

Comment: I posted my answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There would be other ways to resolve `mutating trigger` but I would try to leverage the feature of `compound trigger`. Having said that, we should try to avoid `triggers` generally if possible and in your case call the procedure somewhere in other program units or in application code during the update of `order status` column in `orders` table as I see there is no dependency for each row here and we need to update against the `run_id` and not `order_id`.

Having said that I made some changes to the procedure as we don't need order_id parameter in this use case

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE check_and_update_run_status
(
   in_run_id       IN runs.run_id%TYPE
  ,in_order_status IN orders.order_status%TYPE
) AS
   v_update_run VARCHAR2(1) := 'N';
BEGIN
   /*query the table ORDERS and check if all orders in the given in_run_id having the same status as in_order_status: */
   SELECT CASE
             WHEN NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                   FROM   (SELECT order_id
                                 ,order_status
                           FROM   orders
                           WHERE  run_id = in_run_id)
                   WHERE  order_status <> in_order_status) THEN
              'Y' ELSE 'N'
          END
   INTO   v_update_run
   FROM   dual;

   IF v_update_run = 'Y'
   THEN
      UPDATE runs 
         SET status = in_order_status 
       WHERE run_id = in_run_id;
   END IF;

END check_and_update_run_status;
/
```

And create the `compound trigger` and call the procedure as,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trigger1
   FOR INSERT OR UPDATE OF order_status ON orders
   COMPOUND TRIGGER

   --table type to store the status index by run_id value
   TYPE table_a_row_data_t IS TABLE OF orders.order_status%TYPE INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;

   -- global variable for the compound trigger
   g_row_level_data table_a_row_data_t;

   AFTER EACH ROW IS
   BEGIN
      IF NOT g_row_level_data.exists(:new.run_id)
      THEN
         g_row_level_data(:new.run_id) := :new.order_status;
      END IF;
   END AFTER EACH ROW;

   AFTER STATEMENT IS
   BEGIN
      --loop through all run_id and update the status by calling the procedure
      --here I used collection.first..collection.last as the index is run_id itself  
      FOR runid IN g_row_level_data.first .. g_row_level_data.last
      LOOP
         check_and_update_run_status(in_run_id    => runid
                                    ,in_order_status => g_row_level_data(runid));
      END LOOP;
   END AFTER STATEMENT;
END trigger1;
/
```

Please test and see if it meets your requirement.

Comment: not using the trigger is the best way, you're right. but taking in count that there is thousand places in the project source code where the table **orders** is being updated makes it almost impossible track and change the source code in each and every update case.